# How can I apply shadowing effects to components in codename one

Tags: codenameone

I want to apply some shadowing effects to Label and Button component. Is there any method available in codenameone ? How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this but probably the simplest one is to just incorporate the shadow into the [9-piece border](http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---create-a-9-piece-image-border.html) representing the component. You can also use things like layered layouts or painters to generate such effects, this very much depends on what you need.